# Is this true that the behaviours of moon effects us? Is this believed in in islam?

Tags: hadith, moon

My mother says when it's full moon or new moon, our body pain increases. Like the behaviour of moon affects us. She says that it is also **believed in islam**

So can anyone please tell me if it's true in islam and give me the source (hadith) from where this information comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your mother has possibly misunderstood is that, there is a recommendation by the prophet pbuh, to fast on the mid days of the month. Modern scholars and researchers try to reflect on this by relating it to the full moon state, in which case it has effect on water.

The human body has more than 70% of it to be water, and indeed, the moon in those days might have an effect on your body. So when the prophet pbuh recommended to fast, it might help get less affected by the moon.

In Islam, All power and matter is in the hands of Allah, none can cause you harm nor benefit you except by his permission.
And Allah knows best.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you give me a link of the source or something?

Comment: Abu Dharr narrated that :
the Messenger of Allah said: "O Abu Dharr! When you fast three days out of a month, then fast the thirteenth, fourteenth, and fifteenth." Reference  : Jami` at-Tirmidhi 761
In-book reference  : Book 8, Hadith 80
English translation  : Vol. 2, Book 3, Hadith 761

Comment: 'Abdullah bin 'Amr bin Al-'As (May Allah be pleased with them) reported:
The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "Observing Saum (fasting) on three days of every month is equivalent to a full month's fasting."[Al-Bukhari and Muslim] Book 9, Hadith 1260

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Islam to support this view of your mother. What we find Islam telling us is that the moon has no power. Nor do its cycles or eclipses have anything to do with humans. The Prophet said, ‏ الشمس والقمر لا ينكسفان لموت أحد ولا لحياته، ولكنهما آيتان من آيات الله(The sun and the moon do not eclipse because of someone's death or life but they are two signs amongst the signs of Allah...) - Bukhari (3204). The moon is just reflecting light and it is a sign of the Creator who made it.

This belief that the moon affects people is an assumption among people. This is a good article which mentions why some people associate the moon with effects on people ([BBC Article)](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20131029-does-a-full-moon-make-people-mad) and why it is not a valid conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to share my perspective. I am a Muslim and try to better myself as much as I can in one key area; Character. We live in a day and age where character is lost, those old mannerisms are dying out as new ways of communicating pave the future. Being kind to a stranger in the street is seen as suspicious and when we walk past certain humans, we entertain the notions they might steal our bag. I don’t expect the whole world to suddenly change, although I know my small steps a day are making changes in that very same future. I think it’s very important to be calm, grateful and humble. How simple does that sound, but hardly anyone understands. Like REALLY understands. The way we treat others or even the thoughts of caring about others, it is implementing itself in so many other areas of life. It allows us to grow in areas we are not concerned with because the wiles of modern day have us gripped by the thumbs. I try to focus on my character because I want to treat people in a kind manner, so perhaps something they might do is of the same. The chain will go on and on, a single action that gradually builds momentum.

As for the Moon, I consider myself a Selenophile which I know will sound cringey, it is the truth. Why do I love the Moon? Because it always serves as a reminder to me of my Creator. It is only just one of many, many, many beautiful things our Lord, The Almighty, has created for our pleasure. I do not have any witchy vibes from the Moon, but I truly admire its beauty and creation. I worship my Lord, by which the Moon is just a fascination.

“We will show them Our Signs in the universe, and in their own selves, until it becomes manifest to them that this (the Quran) is the truth” [Fussilat 41:53]

Verily, there are signs for those who see.

Answer (score 0):

This reply will benefit the Muslims cause its based on Quran and Hadith.

Moon has influence on our bodies in one way or the other.As  a Muslim i would like to support my view by the following verse of the Holy Quran and the Saying of the Holy Propeht( Muhammad (صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم)).

Allah says: وَمِن شَرِّ غَاسِقٍ إِذَا وَقَبَ ...."and from the evil of the black darkness whenever it descends,....
The Prophet said:

Aishah narrated:
“The Prophet looked at the moon and he said: ‘O Aishah! Do you seek refuge with Allah from the evil of this? For indeed this is Al-Ghasiqu Idha Waqab (The darkened one as it darkens).’”

https://sunnah.com/urn/744180

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. This answer could be more helpful with some more elaboration. See also [answer].